# Unable to achieve advertised "word-level" accuracy using SyncTeX with PDF Tools

Tags: latex, init-file, auctex, microsoft-windows, pdf-tools

From the AucTeX Changelog (v. 11.89):

> To open the PDF output file you can now also use PDF Tools, a document viewer for Emacs. With it, as a plus, forward and backward search is accurate at word level.

I'm only able to achieve word-level accuracy on reverse sync search. On forward sync search, the arrow that appears in the left-hand margin of the PDF preview buffer can be off by as much as a half-dozen lines.

Is there a way to configure AucTeX + PDF Tools in order to highlight the word in the PDF Tools preview buffer corresponding to where the cursor is positioned in the AucTeX latex source buffer during a forward search instead of placing an arrow in the left-hand margin, which by construction can only be line-level accurate at best?

Emacs 28.2 (MSYS2) w/ latest pdf-tools.